# Does this piecewise function satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations?

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

We were asked if the function:
$$
f(z) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            e^{-1/z^4} & \quad z \neq 0 \\
            0 & \quad z = 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations at $z = 0$.  I don't know how to separate into the form $f(z) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$, and polar form gave me an undefined limit.  The answer is apparently yes, but I'm not satisfied with the explanations I've seen thus far.

Before I tackle that problem, I thought I'd start with a simpler version:

$$
f(z) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            e^{-1/z} & \quad z \neq 0 \\
            0 & \quad z = 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Then, for $z \neq 0$,

$$
e^{\frac{-1}{z}} = e^{\frac{-1}{x+iy}} = e^{\frac{-1}{x+iy}\cdot \frac{x-iy}{x-iy}} = e^{\frac{-x}{x^2+y^2}\cdot} e^\frac{iy}{x^2+y^2} = e^{\frac{-x}{x^2+y^2}} \cdot \left( cos\left(\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \right) + i \ sin \left( \frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \right) \right)
$$

Then we can write $f(z) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$, where

$$
u(x,y) =
\left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            e^{\frac{-x}{x^2+y^2}} \cdot \left( cos\left(\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \right)\right) & \quad (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
            0 & \quad (x,y) = (0,0)
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
$$
v(x,y) =
\left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            e^{\frac{-x}{x^2+y^2}} \cdot \left( sin\left(\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \right)\right) & \quad (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
            0 & \quad (x,y) = (0,0)
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Now, taking the partial derivatives at $z = 0$,

$$
u_x = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{u(0 + \Delta x, 0) - u(0,0)}{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{e^\frac{-\Delta x}{(\Delta x)^2} cos(0) - 0}{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{e^\frac{-1}{\Delta x}}{\Delta x} = 0
$$
$$
v_y = \lim_{\Delta y\to 0} \frac{v(0, 0 + \Delta y) - v(0,0)}{\Delta y} = \lim_{\Delta y\to 0} \frac{e^0 sin(\frac{1}{\Delta y}) - 0}{\Delta y} = \lim_{\Delta y\to 0} \frac{sin(\frac{1}{\Delta y})}{\Delta y}
$$

Did I take the partial derivatives correctly, or make a mistake elsewhere?  Otherwise, I believe the limit for $v_y$ diverges (I tested in Matlab for small $\Delta y$ and does not converge).  It makes intuitive sense since the numerator is bouncing between $-1$ and $1$ and the denominator keeps getting smaller, so I expect this limit does diverge.  But that would mean the Cauchy-Riemann equations are not satisfied, and my intuition is telling me that is wrong.

Comment: Before talking about derivatives, you might investigate whether this function is even continuous on $\mathbb{C}$.  Hint, find $z_0$ with $z_0^4 = i$ and consider $z = tz_0$ as $t \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @JairTaylor I believe it is continuous since $\lim_{z\to 0} e^{-1/z^4} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} e^{-1/(\Delta x)^4} = 0 = f(0)$, where I approach $z = 0$ along $y = 0$.

Comment: If the limit exists is $0$, then the limit will be $0$ regardless of which direction you approach it from.  On the real axis it is continuous, but on $\mathbb{C}$ it is not.

Comment: @JairTaylor: I suspect the point of this exercise is to show that just because the CR equations hold in a point, that doesn't mean that the function is differentiable there, or even continuous. If that's the case, then the equations should still be verified.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291233)

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos, mrf Ah, I see! I had thought that existence of partial derivatives implied continuity, but now I see I was wrong, thanks.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Yes, that is the point of the exercise (follow-up questions ask if the function is continuous and whether it's analytic at $z=0$).

Comment: @mrf Thank you, that question led me to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/104218/90211), which shows me a much simpler way to take the partial derivatives!