# Is my proof that $\operatorname{Log}|z|$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ correct?

Tags: complex-analysis

Note that $\operatorname{Log}|z|$ is the real part of any branch of $\operatorname{log}|z|$, so we pick any of the branches. This branch is analytic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, which means that it's real part is harmonic, and thus the result follows.

That seems too trivial to be correct, is there something wrong with my proof?

Answer (score 1):

$\log|z|$ is not complex analytic in $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$, since $\log|z|$ is real-valued but not constant. The proof does work if you replace $\log|z|$ with $\log z$.

Comment: $\log z$ is not holomorphic on the punctured plane.

Comment: @mrf Yes, but the OP's argument is to choose a branch of $\log z$ to obtain the result in the slit plane. We can then choose two different branches of $\log$, which lets us conclude that the real part is harmonic in the punctured plane, since the real part of a branch of the logarithm doesn't depend on the branch.

Answer (score 1):

You can't choose a branch of $\log z$ that is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, but that's ok. The problem is local and for each point in the punctured plane, you can find a neighbourhood of the point and a corresponding branch of $\log z$ which shows that your function (locally the real part of a holomorphic function) is harmonic.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand it now. But would it not be enough to find a branch of $\operatorname{log}z$ which is complex-differentiable in that point, rather than finding a nbd of that point where it is analytic?

Comment: The condition of being harmonic (or holomorphic) is really something that happens on open sets. It doesn't make sense to talk about functions being "harmonic at a single point" (but there are functions that are complex differentiable only at say $z=0$).

Comment: Sure, the definition says that a function can be harmonic only on open sets, but could I not deduce that the function satisfies Laplace's equation at every point if I reason like this?

Comment: If we are picking nits: there are functions that are complex-differentiable at a single point but where its real and imaginary parts are not twice differentiable. Even more surprising, there are functions satisfying Laplace's equation everywhere without being harmonic. See for example [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61099/do-discontinuous-harmonic-functions-exist/104218#104218). Work on open sets, and you don't have to worry.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost OK. If you want to be more careful, start by picking a branch. With that you prove that $\log \lvert z\rvert$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \text{a half-line}$. Now pick another branch. With that you prove that $\log\lvert z\rvert$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\text{another half-line}$. From that conclude that $\log\lvert z\rvert$ is harmonic in the union of the two domains.

Comment: And now I see that this is exactly the same thing of the other answers. HTH nonetheless