# partial derivatives of a harmonic function are harmonic

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-derivative, harmonic-functions

Let $U \subset \Bbb R^n$ and $f: U \to \Bbb R$ be a harmonic function. I wanna show that the partial derivatives of a harmonic function are harmonic. So for $g= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}$, I wanna show that $\sum_i \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x_i^2}=0$. ( $j \in \{1, \dots , n\}$) I know that f is a function of class $C^2$ but than?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I already saw this but no, not really. For example why we have this: "This is of course assuming that the third partial derivatives of f are well-defined."?

Comment: Yeah but in my case I have to prove that the third partial derivative exist, else I can't show my statement

Comment: I don't know, I doubt it

Comment: A harmonic function is $C^\infty$, not just $C^2$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61101/20569

Comment: Yeah but wow this is quite a hard prove of that fact, is there an easier way to show this?