# Easy way to check that real part of $e^{-\frac{1}{z^{4}}}$ is harmonic.

Tags: harmonic-functions, linear-pde

Let $z=x+i y$ and  $$ u(x,y) = Re \left(e^{-\frac{1}{z^{4}}}\right) ,~ \text{for}~ (x,y) \ne (0,0)$$ and $0$ otherwise. Then is there any short way to check that $u$ satisfies Laplace equation ?

I can apply brute force to check that given function is harmonic in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, but I think there may be some easy way to check it is harmonic.

Comment: Can you show, using the Cauchy--Riemann equations, that the real part of a holomorphic function is harmonic?

Comment: Yes, that is really a nice way.

Comment: Note that you have to check separately that $u$ satisfies the Laplace equation at the origin (see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/104218).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function is holomorphic and the real part of a holomorphic functions is always harmonic.

Answer (score 0):

function is not holomorphic at $z=0$.

$z=0$  is a point of essential singularity.