# Harmonic functions proof

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

[image]

I don't understand here why: $2(\Delta(u_x)^2+\Delta(u_y)^2) \geq 0$.

Here $\Delta= \nabla^2, \quad u'_x=u_x $ etc

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Just apply to $u'_x$ and $u'_y$ what you proved the line above for $u$.

Comment: Are we allowed to say $u_x$ and $u_y$ are harmonic? If I have that $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$ does this imply $u_{xxx}+u_{xyy}=0$? If I just take the partial derivative wrt $x$ of  $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$ and change the order of differentiation it is clear, but how do I know these derivatives exist?

Comment: It is standard, although not really trivial: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55117/smoothness-of-harmonic-functions